# How can I get objects based off of certain associations?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, has-many

I have the following domain classes (Only trying to show what is needed to get the idea) :

```
class Scholarship {

   static hasMany = [grades:Grade]
}
```

and

```
class Grade {

   String id
   String description
}
```

In words I would like to, "Get all scholarships where the associated grade_id = myId". I would like to accomplish this using grails domain classes and not using sql. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?...

```
def results = Scholarship.withCriteria {
    grades {
        // myId must be defined somewhere above...
        idEq myId
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

A comment below adds to the original question and asks what if another relationship was expressed like this...

```
class Scholarship {
    static hasMany = [grades:Grade,majors:Major]     
}
```

The query I show above would still be exactly the same.  The fact that there is a `majors` collection would not be relevant unless you wanted to include some attribute of `Major` to also be part of the criteria, which could look something like this...

```
def results = Scholarship.withCriteria {
    grades {
        // myId must be defined somewhere above...
        idEq myId
    }

    majors {
        // only return Scholarship instances which
        // contain a Major with the name 'Mechanical Engineering'
        eq 'name', 'Mechanical Engineering'
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, but what if I have another has many association, like this:
    `code`class Scholarship {

      static hasMany = [grades:Grade,majors:Major]
    }`code`